# Errors while parsing invalid JSON passed from PHP to AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to parse JSON sent by PHP.

**JSON:**

```
[{"id":"1","value":"1"},{"id":"4","value":"1"},{"id":"2","value":"1"},{"id":"3","value":"1"},{"id":"4","value":"1"}]
```

I'm trying to parse it to get the `id` and pass it to another JavaScript function and I'm continuously calling the PHP. When I tried `$.ajax`, `$.get`, `$.getJSON` and used `JSON.parse` and `parseJSON`, I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

because the JSON looks like this:

```
id: id: id: html> 1id: 4id: 1id: 2id: 3id: 4id: id: id: >
```

I tried to fix it using `JSON.stringify`, which caused this error:

> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 
>   and now I'm stuck and have no idea how to fix this.

**test.php:**

```
<?php
  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");

  if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $db = mysql_select_db("example");

  $sql = "select * from data";
  $x = mysql_query($sql);

  $emparray = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($x)) {
    $emparray[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($emparray);

  mysql_close($link);
?>
```

**heatmap.html:**

```
<script>
        $(window).ready(function(){
          $.ajax({
            url:'test.php',
            data:"{'id':'1', 'value':'1'}", 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: 'json', 
            success: function (data){setInterval(function(){ 
            /* if I use parseJSON(data), I get "Unexpedted token <"
               error */
              $.each(data, function (id, value){ // error occures here
                liveHeatMap(id); //Never called
              });

          }, 10000)}});
        });
</script>
```

I think the problem is that the JSON is invalid. I have tried so many things and looked at many other similar problems but I still cannot fix it.

Comment: Where does the "Unexpected token <" error occur? Is it happening inside the `liveHeatMap()` method that you don't show, or does that function not get called because the error happens before that?

Comment: liveHeatMap() never get called, the "Unexpected token <" occurred when I used  parseJSON(data)

Comment: You shouldn't need to call parseJSON() because jQuery parses the response for you and passes the resulting object to your success handler. (Although you should have `dataType` with a capital "T" in your Ajax options.) Are you sure test.php is returning the right thing? (If you type the test.php url into the browser address bar what do you get?)

Comment: test.php return this: [{"id":"1","value":"1"},{"id":"4","value":"1"},{"id":"2","value":"1"},{"id":"3","value":"1"},{"id":"4","value":"1"}]  and now I'm using this code which also doesn't work but at least there is no errors: $.get('test.php',{'id':'1', 'value':'1'}, setInterval(function(data){
    $.each(data, function (id, value){
      heatmap(id); // never called 
    })
    heatmap(data); // data undefined 
  }, 10000)), 'json'
});

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `contentType` and `dataType` properties in your AJAX request, and use an object (rather than a string) for your `data`. In your `success` function, remove the `setInterval` and manually parse the JSON string returned using `JSON.parse(data)`. This ensures you have the most control over the data to prevent jQuery from causing problems (and also makes it clearer). jQuery may be interfering with the data in the process and you want the complete raw data.

It looks like you're receiving HTML. Common causes:

- Your AJAX URL is pointing to the incorrect place (and it may not seem obvious -- try `./test.php` or using an absolute path).
- Your PHP is not killed after echoing the JSON. Replace `mysql_close($link)` with `die()` as when the script ends, all database connections are automatically closed anyway.

If you're still having issues, run these commands and comment their output:

```
console.log(data);
console.log(typeof data);
```

Comment: @user3505547 That's great! Accept the answer so that others know this is the solution.